# How to use the spec url parameter of the swagger editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I'm trying to pass the spec parameter in the url to the swagger editor to be able to open the API spec passed in the URL

[https://editor.swagger.io/?spec={...}](https://editor.swagger.io/?spec=%7B...%7D)

as documented here:

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

spec    SPEC    Object={}. A JavaScript object describing the OpenAPI definition. When used, the url parameter will not be parsed. This is useful for testing manually-generated definitions without hosting them.

but it seems that doesn't work, [here](https://editor.swagger.io/?spec=%7B%20%22openapi%22:%20%223.0.0%22,%20%22info%22:%20%7B%20%22version%22:%20%221.0.0%22,%20%22title%22:%20%22Swagger%22%20%7D,%20%22paths%22:%20%7B%20%22/mypath%22:%20%7B%20%22get%22:%20%7B%20%22operationId%22:%20%22listPets%22,%20%22parameters%22:%20%5B%20%7B%20%22name%22:%20%22limit%22,%20%22in%22:%20%22query%22,%20%22required%22:%20false,%20%22schema%22:%20%7B%20%22type%22:%20%22integer%22,%20%22format%22:%20%22int32%22%20%7D%20%7D%20%5D,%20%22responses%22:%20%7B%20%22200%22:%20%7B%20%22description%22:%20%22A%20paged%20array%20of%20pets%22%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D) the example

below the spec put in the link:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Swagger"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/mypath": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "listPets",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "limit",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A paged array of pets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be a bug. Please open an issue here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion, I opened the following bug: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/2196